# 3D Perspective in 2D Space

Tags: java, eclipse, 3d, jframe

I'm working in Java with its JFrame. I want to be able to draw 3D objects like a cube.

But I have a problem, I don't know how to calculate the x and y position of where the vertices would go on the z axis.

I'm not working in OpenGL or anything, just using Java's built in features.

I have the window set up and I'm able to draw lines, all I kneed to know to be able to get this to work is the calculation of where the position of vertices on the z axis would be placed in a 2D space.

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is place z as an arbitrary line placed at 45 degrees (assuming you are ok with an isometric view) and place the rest of the lines at the end of the line. keep in mind that you would have to account for scaling in said lines. if you need to actually rotate and operate over the shape, you should really look at the specialized libs i.e. ogl.

Comment: Im wanting to make a camera to move around, eventually to be able to render a scene for a game. so technically drawing 2 cubed and connecting lines wont work the way i want it too. but thanks anyway

Comment: then def do it with OpenGL. no need to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: Its just that OpenGL has more features than I need, creating slower performance and I've got a terrible laptop. Plus, it allows me to know everything going on and not using unnecessary actions. I'm not really ready to make a game engine yet, and its the fun of making this too, good experience!

Comment: I agree that it is a good learning experience, however, it is incorrect to say that because the library has more features that you need it inherently makes it needlessly heavy. your performace will be in accordance to the features used not the features offered. :)

Comment: @Benzaboy "... OpenGL has more features than I need, creating slower performance ..." - there is a reason that devs write AAA games in OpenGL instead of JFrame. Do not confuse "more features" with "slower performance".

Comment: Yeah I understand, but I still want to do it as I want the experience and do it for myself